# Mutate tibble conditionally based on prefixes

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate a tibble based on the following conditions:

- For each row, if the column containing only the prefix, i.e., a or b, has the value 1, other columns starting with the prefix in question should be recoded to 1 as well
- However, for each row, if any of the columns starting with the prefix has the value 1, the values in all rows beginning with that prefix should remain
- The columns that are named with only the prefix should be deleted after the mutation.

A reproducible example is:

```
tibble(a = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
       a.1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
       a.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
       b = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
       b.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
       b.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

# A tibble: 5 × 6
      a   a.1   a.2     b   b.1   b.2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     0     0     0
2     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     0     0     0     0
4     0     0     1     0     1     0
5     1     1     0     1     0     0
```

The end result should look like:

```
tibble(
       a.1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
       a.2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
       b.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
       b.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0,

 1))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
    a.1   a.2   b.1   b.2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0     0
2     0     0     0     0
3     1     0     0     0
4     0     1     1     0
5     1     0     1     1
```

There is not a constant amount of variables for each prefix in my real data. Thus, I am trying to write a general function.

If anyone can help me out, it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't get the second condition, what does it imply on your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `split.default` + `map_dfc`:

```r
tbl %>% 
  split.default(gsub("\\..*", "", colnames(.))) %>% 
  map_dfc(~ {.x[.x[1] == 1 & rowSums(.x[-1]) == 0, ] <- 1
         .x[-1]})
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
    a.1   a.2   b.1   b.2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0     0
2     1     1     0     0
3     1     0     0     0
4     0     1     1     0
5     1     0     1     1
```